# how to use INSTR function to data present in column with data type as CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table(table_clob) which has follwing field

```
create table table_clob ( file_data CLOB);
```

above table has only one row . file_data has following data:

```
"A00",399,"yhnj",20150302,055522,100215 
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"bnncnf","abc","I","XYZ","EA","PO16", Z99,3 
"E51",985856111,147852,10000,"wertt","tgb","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",29 
"E51",456987123,"469555",155000,"reeggdd","edc","D","ABC","EM","GU16","7HF" 52 
"E51",456456852,125500,468566,"wsxcde","BUS","I","ABC","SE","MT12","8JG",18 
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"pokmhj","BUS","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",
```

i have insert above data into a table(including column names and types) . i don't want to insert row starting with 'AOO' and 'Z99' ; after inserting into a table .It should have 6 rows and should look like:

```
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"bnncnf","abc","I","XYZ","EA","PO16", "E51",985856111,147852,10000,"ABC Power Station","BUS","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",29 "E51",985856111,147852,10000,"wertt","tgb","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",29 
"E51",456987123,"469555",155000,"reeggdd","edc","D","ABC","EM","GU16","7HF",52 
"E51",456456852,125500,468566,"wsxcde","yhn","I","ABC","SE","MT12","8JG",18 
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"pokmhj","tgb","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",
```

can anyone help me to get above result

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbms_log.instr packaged function to do this , check the following:

```
select file_data from table_clob
   where dbms_lob.instr(file_data,'AOO')=0 
         or dbms_lob.instr(file_data,'Z99')=0 ;
```

Comment: Do you just want to insert the CLOB column, or do you want to parse the comma-separated values from the CLOB and insert those values into separate columns in the second table? If you want to parse the CLOB, please edit the question and include the description (including column names and types) of the destination table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This query divides clob into individual lines:

```
select 
    substr(file_data, instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level), 
    decode(instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level + 1), 0, length(file_data), 
      instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level + 1) - instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level)-1)
    ) data
  from table_clob
  connect by instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level) > 0
```

Output:

```
DATA                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"bnncnf","abc","I","XYZ","EA","PO16", Z99,3         
"E51",985856111,147852,10000,"wertt","tgb","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ",29        
"E51",456987123,"469555",155000,"reeggdd","edc","D","ABC","EM","GU16","7HF",52   
"E51",456456852,125500,468566,"wsxcde","BUS","I","ABC","SE","MT12","8JG",18      
"E51",987456111,147852,10000,"pokmhj","BUS","I","XYZ","EA","PO16","7GZ"
```

Eliminate unwanted rows for instance `where data not like 'Z99'` and insert into table like here:

```
insert into table_clob (file_data) 
select data from
  (select 
      substr(file_data, instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level), 
      decode(instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level + 1), 0, length(file_data), 
        instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level + 1) - instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level)-1)
      ) data
    from table_clob
    connect by instr(file_data, '"E51"', 1, level) > 0)
  where data not like 'Z99'
```

Comment: I got how to extract different rows but let us assume that my target table has columns from column 1  to column 12 . In this 12 column of my target table i have to insert the above data.After inserting it should populate the table with 5 rows . Above query is giving me output in CLOB format .How to  do this ????

Comment: In this case I would use SQLLoader. But SQL solution is also possible, you need to split resulted rows into columns similarly like I splitted CLOB - example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement) for instance.